# Issue with Log files generation with log4j

Tags: java, scala, playframework, log4j, filewriter

I am trying to records the error, but below code not working its create the `error.txt` but doesn't write on it.

### I have imported these files:

```
import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
import org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory
```

---

My function:

```
  def errorLogs(data: String) {
    println("data"+data)
    val logg = Logger.getLogger(data)
    val loger = Logger.getRootLogger()
    loger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val layout = new PatternLayout("[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m %d{ISO8601} %n")
    loger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(layout))
    try {
      val fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(layout, "error.txt")
      loger.addAppender(fileAppender)
      loger.removeAppender(fileAppender)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        println("Exception in sessionLogs e=" + e)
        logg.error("sessionLogs-" + e)
    }
  }
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can this be as simple as the fact that you're calling `removeAppender` on the `fileAppender` right after adding it and therefore subsequent calls to `error` method will not use this appender?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you should write error message to `loger`. Try `loger.error(data)` in the last line of the `errorLogs` function.